# alternative for specifying excel sheet name in OledbCommand

Tags: c#, excel

i want to know alternative way of specfifying sheet name in OledbCommand.The end user can import data from any sheet to database.So i want to provide flexibility in providing sheet name..what ever the sheet is selected by end user that data gets imported to database.

I have written the statement in this manner:

```
    OleDbDataAdapter data = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Customers$]", cnn);
```

I want to know the other way of mentioning sheet name to provide flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you provide the sheetname using a variable? Something like this:

```
var sheetName = "Customers$";
OleDbDataAdapter data = new OleDbDataAdapter(string.Format("select * from [{0}]", sheetName), cnn);
```

Comment: Sorry for late response..was busy with other requirement..i want to know if i use the stmt which u have mentioned for specifying sheetname..will it give the flexibility to end user to select any sheetname..Suppose it is not customer sheet the end user has selected some other sheet from excel file..so will the above stmt work properly..